# playing a windows media file vba a few times

Tags: windows, vba, excel, media

I've created a one octave piano in excel VBA.  Using the keys as images with a sub attached to each which plays a note.  I've added the capability to record your played notes using this code for each "note", optionbutton1 being the "you are now recording" selection.

```
Private Sub A_Click()
WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "F:\New Folder\puzzles\Anote.wav"
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
   Dim x As String
   x = "A"
   Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
   ActiveCell.Value = x
End If
End Sub
```

Where my issue comes in is playing the recording.  I need to loop through all the cells.  I'm using a For Each Loop.  The if statement will of course be expanded to encompass the entire octave.

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
If cell.Value = "A" Then
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "F:\New Folder\puzzles\Anote.wav"
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.play 
ElseIf cell.Value = "C" Then
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "F:\New Folder\puzzles\Cnote.wav"
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.play 
End If
Next cell
```

To see it go through I put an action wait and it cycles through the cells just fine and when I put a code that just changes the values of the cells it does that too, but with the sounds it only plays a note once it gets to the last cell.

I figure that I have to be be doing something wrong with the media player controls, but I can't figure out what.
Thanks,

Comment: Upvote just for `octave piano in excel VBA`